# Datastax/Cassandra module php don't work with pcntl_fork

Tags: php, cassandra, pcntl

Datastax/Cassandra perfect work in single script. But I need create many fork with pcntl_fork. And in fork cassandra don't work.
simple script

```
    <?php
$cluster   = Cassandra::cluster()                 // connects to localhost by default
                 ->build();
$keyspace  = 'system';
$session   = $cluster->connect($keyspace);        // create session, optionally scoped to a keyspace
$statement = new Cassandra\SimpleStatement(       // also supports prepared and batch statements
    'SELECT keyspace_name, columnfamily_name FROM schema_columnfamilies'
);
$future    = $session->executeAsync($statement);  // fully asynchronous and easy parallel execution
$result    = $future->get();
```

If run as single script $result content data. If I create pcntl_fork script freezes on $future->get(). How fix?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is all the children and the parent processes share the same underlying sockets and there isn't a portable or robust way for the php-driver to handle this. A good way to handle this in your application is to connect after the fork; here is some psuedo code for a single forked process:

```
$cluster = Cassandra::cluster()->build();

// Perform fork

if ($pid) { // Parent process
    $session = $cluster->connect($keyspace);

    // Do parent stuff
} else { // Child process
    $session = $cluster->connect($keyspace);

    // Do child stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm creating connect after fork, but it work only if not created connect in parent proccess. If in parent proccess created connect then don't connected in child proccess, not looking at the fact that i'm creating new connect.